# Generate URL in Symfony 5 with GET parameters

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, url

In Symfony 5, I would like to generate an URL partially based on GET paramaters already posted.

Let's assume that the URL posted is:

```
user/edit/5?foo=1&bar=1&baz=1&qux=1
```

I would like to generate in the controller without `foo`:

```
user/edit/5?bar=1&baz=1&qux=1
```

First, I remove `foo` parameter :

```
$request->query->remove('foo');
```

If I didn't get the `user_id` in the URL as route parameter (5), I would use:

```
$this->generateUrl('user_edit', $request->query->all());
```

But this is not working because `user_id` is missing. So how can I generated such URL without rewriting all variables:

```
$this->generateUrl('user_edit', ['id' => $user->getId(), ???]);
```

I was thinking about PHP function `array_merge()` but this seems to me more a trick than an elegant solution:

```
$this->generateUrl('user_edit', array_merge(
    ['id' => $user->getId()],
    $request->query->all())
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in using `array_merge()`. That's exactly what you want to accomplish. It's not a "trick", it's a language feature.

If you want a less verbose syntax, just use `+`.

```php
$this->generateUrl('user_edit', $request->query->all() + ['id' => $user->getId()]);
```

The end result is exactly the same for the above, and it's shorter.